# Apply Left Inner Join in EF MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following SQL Syntax:

```
select      a.year, a.Month, 
            a.DocumentNumber, b.BoxNumber, 
            c.LocationShortName, d.RackShortName
from        MasterAP a 
            left join RecordManagementAP b on a.MasterAPID = b.MasterAPID
            left join MasterLocation c on b.LocationID = c.LocationID
            left join MasterRack d on b.RackID = d.RackID
where       a.Month = '2'
```

How can I apply that syntax into EF sytax in MVC? My current syntax in EF is:

```
var recordManagementAPs = db.RecordManagementAPs.Include(r => r.MasterAP).Include(r => r.MasterLocation).Include(r => r.MasterRack);
return View(recordManagementAPs.ToList());
```

Any idea?
Really appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection.

Declare a view model for the data for your view. (rather than passing entities.)

```
[Serializable]
public class RecordDetailViewModel
{
    public int MasterAPId { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string BoxNumber { get; set; }
    public string LocationShortName { get; set; }
    public string RackShortName { get; set; }
}
```

Project your entity query into the view model and return:

```
var viewModels = db.MasterAPs
    .Where(x => x.Month == month) // "2"
    .Select(x => new RecordDetailViewModel
    {
        MasterAPId = x.MasterAPId,
        Year = x.Year,
        Month = x.Month,
        DocumentNumber = x.DocumentNumber,
        BoxNumber = x.RecordManagementAP.BoxNumber,
        LocationShortName = x.MasterLocation.LocationShortName,
        RackShortName = x.MasterRack.RackShortName
     }).ToList();
```

Assuming that your entity relationships have been mapped.

The `Include` keyword is used when you are returning entire entities and want to pre-fetch the related entities (Include them) rather than lazy load them if they are accessed. Typically you should only retrieve entities (and related entities) when you want to do something like an update where you either accept a view model or set of fields to update from the view, load the entity(ies) and apply the updates before saving the entities.  Don't pass entities to the views. This exposes more information than you need to about your domain, requires more memory, and can lead to errors or performance pitfalls when serializing relationships. Receiving entities from views is worse as it can leave your system vulnerable to unexpected tampering, potential attaching reference errors, and overwriting data with stale changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query following ways:

```
var query = (from a in Context.MasterAP
            join b in Context.RecordManagementAP on new { a.MasterAPID } equals new { b.MasterAPID }
            into b1
            from b in b1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join c in Context.MasterLocation on new { b.LocationID } equals new { c.LocationID }
            into c1
            from c in c1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join d in Context.MasterRack on new { b.RackID } equals new { d.RackID }
            into d1
            from d in d1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where a.Month == 2
            select new //Write YourModelName Here After new kwyword
            {
                Year = a.Year,
                Month = a.Month,
                DocumentNumber = a.DocumentNumber,
                BoxNumber = b.BoxNumber,
                LocationShortName = c.LocationShortName, 
                RackShortName = d.RackShortName
            });
```